# Why is an empty string rendered in vue.js template considered truthy?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Why does an empty string in a vue template return as truthy?

```
<div>{{ "" ?? "empty string is not truthy" }}</div>
```

This will just display the empty string. I have a bunch of empty string fields which I can't check with the [nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) but instead have to use ternaries:

```
<div>{{ "" ? "string empty" : "string not empty" }}</div>
```

Shouldn't `"" ??` be faulty?

Comment: The nullish coalescing operator will **only** short circuit with `null` or `undefined`, not any falsey value, [and the documentation is quite clear on that point](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing). It's even in the *name*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) tests if a value is not `null` or `undefined`, not if it is truthy.

`""` is a falsy value, but it isn't `null` and it isn't `undefined`.

Use the [Logical OR (||) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) to test for truthiness.